# Javascript array find check for undeifned

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, find

I am using javascript array.find on my list of object arrays. I want to get another property of that object only when compared to that
property is available.
When compared to t, I get value as 'Value1'
When compared to t1, I get undefined. I want to check for 'undefined' and get the value only when available.

```
const t = 'abc';
const t1= 'xyz';
temp = [ {key: "abc", value: "Value1}]
temp.find( check => check.key === t ).value);
```

Comment: It would appear you are missing a double quote after Value1 => `value: "Value1"}` Also remove the extra `)` from the end of `temp.find( check => check.key === t ).value;`

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to throw an error, return undefined, return a default or something else, you can check for undefined like so:

```
x = list.find(logic)
if(x){
    //carry on as normal     
else{
    //handle it not being found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you were missing a closing quote. Secondly, use `some` and `find`:

```js
const t = 'abc';
const t1= 'xyz';
const temp = [{key: "abc", value: "Value1"}];
if (temp.some(({ key }) => key == t)) console.log(temp.find(({ key }) => key == t).value);
```

Comment: I want to do it in one statement instead of using another variable like 'found' to check.

Comment: Instead of using some, is there any way just with find using a turnery operator

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you intend to use the value, you will likely find you need some type of value as a result of your search. This will allow you to substitute something or nothing as needed.

```js
const t = 'abc';
const t1= 'xyz';
temp = [ {key: "abc", value: "Value1"}]
const result = temp.find( check => check.key === t1 ) || {value:'Not Found!'};
console.log(result.value);
```